# Catching PlatformException in async function in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

## Background

I am trying to fetch a booking document from `Firestore` inside the `initState()` method of my `State`.
This is also my first time using flutter/dart, so apologies if I am making a very rookie mistake.

## Problem

When I run the `get()` method, an `async` function that returns a `Future<DocumentSnapshot>`, an error is thrown. I am trying to catch and handle this error. The error is an 'insufficient permissions' error which I intend to get.

## My code

```dart
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final firestoreInstance = Firestore.instance;
  Future<DocumentSnapshot> _futureBooking;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    try {
      _futureBooking = firestoreInstance
          .collection('bookings')
          .document('1Twgjq5YTe3Oa12wwbs1')
          .get();
    } catch (err) {
      print("error fetching from firestore: $err");
    }
  }
```

## Results

The `catch` block is never entered, and the app always crashes when making the `get()` call.

[image]

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Please copy-paste errors directly into the question with the formatting tools that are provided.

Comment: Also addressing your thought of you retrieving the `Future` in `initState` being a mistake, this is actually the intended method retrieving a `Future` for `FutureBuilder`(assuming you're using it to display what you retrieve) according to the docs. Many people don't do this, instead retrieving the `Future` in `build` without really understanding the consequences. There may be some cases where this is intended of course.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't catch errors with `try-catch` blocks when you're not using `await`.

To catch errors in the way that you want to call this future function, use the [`catchError`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.4/dart-async/Future/catchError.html) method of the `Future` class.
Ex.

```dart
_futureBooking = firestoreInstance
  .collection('bookings')
  .document('1Twgjq5YTe3Oa12wwbs1')
  .get()
  .catchError(
    (err) {
      print("error fetching from firestore: $err");
    }
  );
```

Alternatively, you could still use `try-catch` and with `await`, while still maintaining your functionality. Ex.

```dart
Future<DocumentSnapshot> wrapperFunction() async {
  try {
    return await firestoreInstance
      .collection('bookings')
      .document('1Twgjq5YTe3Oa12wwbs1')
      .get();
  } catch (err) {
    print("error fetching from firestore: $err");
  }
}

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  _futureBooking = wrapperFunction();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, worked great. As it turns out, my app was not actually crashing, but simply breaking on exceptions.. silly me. Since I am using a `FutureBuilder`, I removed the `try / catch` altogether and allow the exception to set the snapshots `hasError` method to `true`. But very useful to know how to do this nonetheless. Thanks again!

Comment: (important)And please note that all these Catching Platform Exception is work only with 'Release Vestion', It will not work on debugging.

Comment: @gsm That is incorrect. All exceptions can be caught regardless of the compilation mode. If this is something you personally experienced, it is due to a setting in your IDE to catch all exceptions whether they are caught or not. There was also a bug(may or may not be fixed) in VS code that prevented that setting from being disabled.